# What is going on with the Raspberry PI SPI? Weird jitter in signal

Tags: raspbian, spi, raspberry-pi-os, signal

I'm using python and spidev to do spi transactions over the Raspberry Pi's spi channel. I'm having a couple of different things happen that are not what I am expecting.

[image: Oscilloscope]

This is a capture of a spi transaction. Channel 1 is the SCLK Channel 2 is the SDI and Channel 4 is the CSB. It's worth noting that for my application I need 4 CSB lines. Due to this I am manually driving the 4 GPIO pins using another library and just leaving the dedicated spi lines unconnected.   There are a few things here that are going wrong.

First of all the jitter, around the center of the oscilloscope you can see weird jitter in all three signals. I am unsure as to what is causing this but would like to eliminate it as I believe it may be causing issues.

Secondly the clock frequency, in my code I am setting the frequency to 100kHz yet the recorded frequency is 40kHz this seems to be a known issue with SPI on the Rpi but I haven't found any ways to ensure that I can get my desired frequency.

Any insights into what could be happening here would be very appreciated I am not sure what things I should be looking into to find the solution to this.

Comment: Weird jitter sounds like a wiring problem. Wrong frequency sounds like a programming error.

Comment: Someone posted about a suspect power supply. Are you using an official Pi power supply? https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=306499

Comment: What exactly is CSB? Chipselect?